# userId from onCreateUser gets deleted in associated records

Tags: meteor

I need to create some new documents that references a user through his ID, when creating a new user

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  console.log(user);

  var google = user.services.google;
  var tokens = {
    accessToken: google.accessToken,
    // refreshToken: google.refreshToken
  };

  if (tokens.accessToken) {
    Meteor.call('createChannel', user._id, tokens, function(error, result) {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    });
  }
  return user;
});
```

Inside the `createChannel` method, I use the passed in id `user._id`, to setup some documents that references the user documents.

```
createChannel: function(userId, tokens) {
    console.log(userId);

    var missionId = Meteor.call('createDefaultMission', userId);
    ... 

  /* Creates a new mission with default values
   */
  createDefaultMission: function(userId) {
    doc = {
      _id: Random.id(),
      userId: userId,
      name: 'My Mission',
    };

    var missionId = Missions.insert(doc);
    return missionId;
  },
```

Problem is, in this case the Mission record doesn't have any userId field after creation. When using SimpleSchema, I get an `User is required` error.

Any idea as to why this is?

UPDATE

```
createDefaultMission: function(userId) {
    doc = {
      _id: Random.id(),
      userId: userId,
      name: 'My Mission',
    };

    console.log(doc); <----- this logs the above with the userId field filled
    console.log(Meteor.users.findOne(userId)); <----- this finds the user with the above ID

    var missionId = Missions.insert(doc); <---- this failed, userId field is not present
    return missionId;
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

The `userId` isn't generated until after `onCreateUser` has finished executing. See [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/419) for more details. You can get around this by using a [collection hook](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) like the following:

```js
Meteor.users.after.insert(function(userId, doc) {
  var google = doc.services.google;
  var tokens = {accessToken: google.accessToken};
  Meteor.call('createChannel', userId, tokens);
});
```

Comment: Okay I did this, but still, the userId doesnt get inserted along with the rest. Updated post

Comment: What you wrote doesn't seem possible. I suspect the way you are querying the collection isn't correct. I suggest doing a `console.log(missionId)` and then looking up the mission by that id. Alternatively, just reset your db so you can just do `Missions.findOne()`.